# Apache 2.4 can't read user content even with correct security context and booleans set

Tags: selinux

I have a user's home directory at /data/test_user. I am using indexing to allow browsing this directory via web browser with Apache 2.4. However, all of a sudden I'm getting an issue where I can't see any contents. Note that I can see the directory, and can enter it, but when I do there are no contents shown (even if there are in the filesystem). Specifically, there is on file in there named `testfile`

This directory has the following label:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 test_user
```

`/home/test_user/testfile` label and permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--. test_user remote-users unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 testfile
```

Additionally, I have the following booleans set:

```
httpd_can_network_relay        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network relay
httpd_can_connect_mythtv       (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect mythtv
httpd_can_network_connect_db   (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect db
httpd_use_gpg                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use gpg
httpd_dbus_sssd                (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to dbus sssd
httpd_enable_cgi               (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to enable cgi
httpd_verify_dns               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to verify dns
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs    (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to dontaudit search dirs
httpd_use_cifs                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use cifs
httpd_manage_ipa               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to manage ipa
httpd_run_stickshift           (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to run stickshift
httpd_enable_homedirs          (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to enable homedirs
httpd_dbus_avahi               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to dbus avahi
httpd_unified                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to unified
httpd_mod_auth_pam             (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to mod auth pam
httpd_can_network_connect      (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect
httpd_execmem                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to execmem
httpd_use_fusefs               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use fusefs
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind    (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to mod auth ntlm winbind
httpd_use_sasl                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use sasl
httpd_tty_comm                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to tty comm
httpd_sys_script_anon_write    (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to sys script anon write
httpd_graceful_shutdown        (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to graceful shutdown
httpd_can_connect_ftp          (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect ftp
httpd_run_ipa                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to run ipa
httpd_read_user_content        (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to read user content
httpd_use_nfs                  (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use nfs
httpd_can_connect_zabbix       (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect zabbix
httpd_tmp_exec                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to tmp exec
httpd_run_preupgrade           (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to run preupgrade
httpd_can_sendmail             (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can sendmail
httpd_builtin_scripting        (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to builtin scripting
httpd_can_connect_ldap         (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect ldap
httpd_can_check_spam           (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can check spam
httpd_can_network_memcache     (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network memcache
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect cobbler
httpd_anon_write               (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to anon write
httpd_serve_cobbler_files      (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to serve cobbler files
httpd_ssi_exec                 (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to ssi exec
httpd_use_openstack            (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to use openstack
httpd_enable_ftp_server        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to enable ftp server
httpd_setrlimit                (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to setrlimit
```

SELinux Alerts:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from getattr access on the file /data/test_user/testfile.

*****  Plugin restorecon (99.5 confidence) suggests   ************************

If you want to fix the label.
/data/test_user/testfile default label should be default_t.
Then you can run restorecon.
Do
# /sbin/restorecon -v /data/test_user/testfile

*****  Plugin catchall (1.49 confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that httpd should be allowed getattr access on the testfile file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'httpd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-httpd
# semodule -i my-httpd.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0
Target Objects                /data/test_user/testfile [ file ]
Source                        httpd
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/httpd
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          <redacted>
Source RPM Packages           httpd-2.4.6-45.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-102.el7_3.15.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     <redacted>
Platform                      Linux 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
                              #1 SMP Mon Feb 20 02:37:52 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   16
First Seen                    2017-03-16 22:36:36 UTC
Last Seen                     2017-03-22 19:10:23 UTC
Local ID                      a6ae731b-71aa-446f-9be7-445e3656ef06

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1490209823.491:352): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=2508 comm="httpd" path="/data/test_user/testfile" dev="dm-0" ino=2122369 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=file


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1490209823.491:352): arch=x86_64 syscall=lstat success=no exit=EACCES a0=7ffe31303d60 a1=7ffe31303c70 a2=7ffe31303c70 a3=6d69762e726f6c items=0 ppid=2503 pid=2508 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=httpd exe=/usr/sbin/httpd subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: httpd,httpd_t,user_home_dir_t,file,getattr
```

I also have everything in the /data/ with the following default context:

```
/data(/.*)?                                        all files          system_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0
```

What am I missing here? This was previously working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at `sesearch --allow -s httpd_t -b httpd_read_user_content | grep user_home_dir_t` shows that in fact, SELinux is working correctly:

```
   allow httpd_t user_home_dir_t : lnk_file { read getattr } ;
   allow httpd_t user_home_dir_t : dir { getattr search open } ;
   allow httpd_t user_home_dir_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ;
   allow httpd_t user_home_dir_t : dir { getattr search open } ;
```

The important factor here is that I was wanting the files within the directory read, not just the directory. However, if we change the context to `user_home_t` it allows apache to read files within the directory, as explained by `sesearch --allow -s httpd_t -b httpd_read_user_content | grep user_home_t`

```
   allow httpd_t user_home_type : dir { getattr search open } ;
   allow httpd_t user_home_type : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ;
   allow httpd_t user_home_type : dir { getattr search open } ;
   allow httpd_t user_home_type : file { ioctl read getattr lock open } ;
```

The specific line of interest here is the `file` at the very end, showing that apache can have ioctl read getattr lock and open on files with this context. Labeling the directory with the `user_home_t` allowed me to see the files in the index listing without issue.

Comment: Just FYI, Fedora, at least, has a file context `httpd_user_content_t` that's set on `$HOME/public_html/` directories (and their contents), and that's used to grant apache access to the web content in home directories (in concert with the `httpd_enable_homedirs` boolean).